# Audio recording with HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, audio, recording, getusermedia

I'm trying to implement audio recording in a website. Basically the user should be able to press a button and speak something into the microphone. The recorded audio should then be sent to the server for further processing. I realise that you can do this with Flash, but for now I'm trying to avoid that.

I found several resources on the internet about it (i.e. [link](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/)) but as it seems, this functionality is not widly supported yet. I experienced differences betweet the used browser and between the used operating system. For instance, the Chrome Browser doesn't seem to access any microphone on Linux correctly. So i was wondering if anyone knows a good resource to dive into this. Or maybe someone tried to set up something like this himself, and can help with some suggestions about where the limitations of HTML5 and the JavaScript Web Audio API are right now.

Thanks!

Comment: You can now use [Recorder.js](https://addpipe.com/blog/using-recorder-js-to-capture-wav-audio-in-your-html5-web-site/) , [WebAudioRecorder.js](https://addpipe.com/blog/using-webaudiorecorder-js-to-record-audio-on-your-website/) or [vmsg](https://addpipe.com/blog/recording-mp3-audio-in-html5-using-vmsg-a-webassembly-library-based-on-lame/).

Answer (score 2):

As of Chrome Version 27.0.1453.56 beta Mac, audio recording works with this demo application https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs

This app returns back a WAV file for the user which can be uploaded to the server.

If you want a truly robust solution that works on most desktop web browsers, you may need to resort to Flash.

Comment: Thanks, i already knew about recorder.js and tried it at my project. It really makes life a litte bit easier. The browser issues remain though (which is not a suprise). But I found a very strange behaviour with Chrome and Linux. I had the problem, that everything worked fine, Chrome seemed to found my microphone but when I recorded something, the produces wav file was empty...just a whole bunch of zeros in it. But then when I navigated to `chrome://flags/` it worked. And I didn't even change anything in the settings, I just navigated to the page. But that's probably another question.

Comment: are you using stable chrome or the beta? might be good to report it as a bug for the linux version.

Comment: @basilikum Having the exact same issue on windows 8 in chrome  28.0.1500.95 but still havn't found a way to get it working yet.

Answer (score 1):

This article covers up pretty well the current state of audio video capture possibilites using HTML5:

http://hdfvr.com/html5-video-recording

Also for just audio capture, here's a gitHub project that records audio to mp3 directly from the browser:

https://github.com/nusofthq/Recordmp3js