# How to record voice in the client-side without Flash?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, voice-recording

We need to capture voice in a web portal. Our contractor developed the whole web portal without using Java Applications, only client-side code, and claims there is no way to capture voice using JavaScript today.

I'm not a Java guy, so I don't have the skills to discuss this, but I'll appreciate any help our folks here in SO can give: if you guys say it can not be done with today technology, so be it...

PS: the solution MUST attend IE, Chrome, Firefox and Safari, for end users, so Canary is out of question for now.

Comment: Are you looking for Java or for Javascript?

Comment: It's experimental still but there is [`navigator.getUserMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator.getUserMedia) (with browser prefixes), which lets you access a connected webcam, microphone or both through _JavaScript_.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 record audio to file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413063/html5-record-audio-to-file)

Comment: Please refer <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718183/recording-html5-audio> <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761496/audio-recording-with-html5><http://codeartists.com/post/36746402258/how-to-record-audio-in-chrome-with-native-html5-apis>

Comment: this very much depends on what browsers are you targeting - as @PaulS. pointed out, you can get an experimental functionality to work on the very latest bleeding-edge browsers but this is unstable and likely to change in the future... so yes, there is no *reliable* way to do it via JavaScript just yet

Comment: Try this http://www.sajithmr.me/jrecorder-jquery

Comment: Thanks @Bergi: it must be javascript, that's why I use the proper tag in the question.

Comment: @PaulS.: thank you for the experimental function tip and the possible duplicate advice, I edited the question to make clear we need a broader reach of browsers.

Comment: @tcbrazil: if it's JavaSript only, then that's more specific than "without Flash". See [using JavaScript to record in a web app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15082689/can-i-use-javascript-to-record-voice-on-a-web-app)

Comment: Dan Dascalescu, the solution you noted uses HTML5, that doesn't works in all browsers. And I believe it must be "without Flash", since JavaScript and Flash are not mutually exclusive...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there's no way reliable way to record audio using only HTML5 and JavaScript across browsers.

The only cross browser solution for non Flash recording on desktop browsers **in the foreseeable future** is the [Media Recorder API](https://addpipe.com/blog/mediarecorder-api/). It's a recent standard proposal for a JS API who's purpose is to make audio and video recording in the browser very simple. Today it works only in Firefox 27 and only for audio. [This article](https://addpipe.com/blog/mediarecorder-api/) covers the standard in more detail.

**If audio recording is important for you today** I recommend you check out proven flash solutions like FLVAR or [Audior](http://audior.ec/). They work on all browsers, they are reliable and supported. Flash just works and major sites like YouTube and Netflix continue to use it.

Comment: Tks Octavian, but since both FLVAR and Audior are Flash apps, I don't think they'll work on Safari.

Comment: Safari on Mac OSX supports Flash Player and the browser is supported by both Audio and FLVAR.

Answer (score 1):

The javascript's getUserMedia ([getUserMedia on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator.getUserMedia)) is a simple way to do this. I suggest you [addyosmani's polyfill](https://github.com/addyosmani/getUserMedia.js) that has a flash fallback in case the browser doesn't yet support it.

Comment: Thanks @Antonio-e, but this API does not work in IE.